# Qual a diferença entre "semana passada" e "semana retrasada"?

Tags: significado, diferenças

Qual é a diferença e qual a utilização correta de *semana passada* e *semana retrasada*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Semana passada*** refere-se à semana anterior à atual. Enquanto [***semana retrasada*** (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/retrasada) faz referência à semana anterior à passada.

Num exemplo simples, supondo que hoje seja dia 20 do mês, o dia 15 foi na semana passada e o dia 7 na semana retrasada.

Comment: Incluí um link ao dicionário, que me parece ficar bem  na resposta.